# What is an Idiom for badgering by asking if a person is well when no illness present?

Tags: idiom-meaning

Continually asking an individual questions below when there is no reason to believe a person isn't okay with the purpose of picking on them. Or to question sanity of an idea.

Are you feeling okay?
Are you Well?

Comment: What's wrong with *badgering*?

Comment: If you left out *Or to question sanity of an idea* everything else would mean exactly the same and Mick's Comment would still seem perfect.

What d'you think *Or to question sanity of an idea* changes, please?